# What does @pragma("vm:prefer-inline") mean in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have seen a lot of code, like following, in frameworks.
What does the `@pragma` annotation do?

```dart
@pragma("vm:entry-point", "call")
@pragma("vm:entry-point", "set")
@pragma("vm:entry-point", "get")
@pragma("vm:prefer-inline")`
......
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

For the general meaning of `@pragma` cfr above the [NKSM's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64342987/13303234).

I will cite two important specific use case:

- `@pragma('vm:prefer-inline')` to **inline functions**

  (I mean compile-time inlining, which has nothing to do with 'inline function' intended as a synonym for *closure/lambda*, as is sometimes done)

  This annotation is similar to [inline keyword in Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inline-functions.html)
- `@pragma("vm:entry-point")` to mark a function (or other entities, as classes) to indicate to the compiler that it will be **used from native code**. Without this annotation, the dart compiler could strip out unused functions, inline them, shrink names, etc, and the native code would fail to call it.

  A very good doc (written much more clearly than usual) about `entry-point` is https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/runtime/docs/compiler/aot/entry_point_pragma.md

If you want to do a first test with inlining in dart, I suggest you compile with **dart2js**, which outputs fairly readable javascript code (at least until you increase the shrinking level beyond the default one; and readability is obviously decent only in minimal programs). However, inlining in dart/js requires a slightly different @pragma annotation: `@pragma ('dart2js: tryInline')`.

An interesting discussion about inlining in dart can be found in
[dart-lang issue #40522 - Annotation for method inlining](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/40522)

In general, I suggest [Mraleph blog](https://mrale.ph). His latest article is on benchmarking in dart, and also shows the use of `@pragma(vm:entry-point)`. Mraleph is a Dart Sdk developer (he is also an author of the official doc cited above), and it is a very precious source about Dart VM related topics.

Answer (score 8):

Flutter uses the **[Dart](https://dart.dev/guides)** programming language.

The **Pragma class** functions as a guiding tool for various aspects of *Dart programming*.

In *Dart programs*, we can provide hints to tools using pragma annotations on declarations. These hints serve as suggestions that different tools interpret in their own ways. Tools have the autonomy to choose which hints they understand, how to interpret them, and where to apply them in the code.

The `@pragma("vm:prefer-inline")` is a specific hint used in *Flutter* and *Dart* to influence the *Dart virtual machine* (VM)'s optimization process. This pragma suggests to the *Dart VM* that it should prioritize inlining (or inline-expanding) certain functions during optimization. Inlining is an optimization technique where the code of a called function is inserted directly into the calling function, eliminating the overhead of a function call.

Marking a function with `@pragma("vm:prefer-inline")` implies that they believe inlining that particular function would lead to improved performance. Here's an example:

```dart
@pragma("vm:prefer-inline")
void myFooInlineFunction() {
  // Function code
}
```

This indicates to the *Dart VM* that it should consider inlining `myFooInlineFunction` wherever it is called, with the expectation of performance gains. It's important to use such hints judiciously, considering the specific characteristics of the code and the potential impact on performance.

---

In cases where hints can have parameters, an extra options object can be included to provide more specific information.

For example:

```
@pragma('Tool:pragma-name', [param1, param2, ...])
class Foo { }

@pragma('OtherTool:other-pragma')
void foo() { }
```

> Here class **Foo** is annotated with a Tool specific pragma 'pragma-name'
> and function foo is annotated with a pragma 'other-pragma' specific to
> OtherTool.

The above can be found on [dart.dev documentation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.1.0/dart-core/pragma-class.html).

---

The `@pragma("vm:entry-point")` annotation is essential for Tree-Shaking during AOT(Ahead of Time) compilation. In AOP(Aspect-Oriented Programming), non-invasive injected logic might not be called directly by the main entry point. Without this annotation, the compiler could discard such logic as unused. By using `@pragma('vm:entry-point')`, we instruct the compiler to retain this code during compilation, preventing unintended exclusion.

Comment: this does not answer the question

Comment: @nt4f04und yet,But he gave an idea.I have a general understanding of what pragma is for, but I still don't understand how it works.

Comment: This is almost entirely a copy-paste from the official documentation.