# How to Get Push Notification in Foreground IOS Using Flutter 2024

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

Currently, I'm building an app that has feature push notifications using Flutter and integrates with Firebase. For Android, it worked fine, and for iOS, it was also working fine, but I noticed that notifications do not appear when in foreground mode on iOS, but I can receive notifications when I manually scroll the system tray or notification center.

Is it possible to get pushed into the foreground using Flutter?

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import '../../firebase_options.dart';
import 'awesome_notifications_helper.dart';

class FcmHelper {
  // prevent making instance
  FcmHelper._();

  // FCM Messaging
  static late FirebaseMessaging messaging;

  /// this function will initialize firebase and fcm instance
  static Future<void> initFcm() async {
    try {
      // initialize fcm and firebase core
      await Firebase.initializeApp(
        options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
      );

      // initialize firebase
      messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

      // notification settings handler
      await _setupFcmNotificationSettings();

      // generate token if it not already generated and store it on shared pref
      await _generateFcmToken();
      // send message for multiple devices
      FirebaseMessaging.instance.subscribeToTopic('NITH');
      // background and foreground handlers
      FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen(_fcmForegroundHandler);
      FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_fcmBackgroundHandler);
      FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen(_onMessageOpenApp);
    } catch (error) {
      // if you are connected to firebase and still get error
      // check the todo up in the function else ignore the error
      // or stop fcm service from main.dart class
      // Logger().e(error);
    }
  }

  ///handle fcm notification settings (sound,badge..etc)
  static Future<void> _setupFcmNotificationSettings() async {
    //show notification with sound and badge
    messaging.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
      alert: true,
      sound: true,
      badge: true,
    );

    //NotificationSettings settings
    await messaging.requestPermission(
      alert: true,
      announcement: false,
      badge: true,
      carPlay: false,
      criticalAlert: false,
      provisional: false,
      sound: true,
    );
  }

  /// generate and save fcm token if its not already generated (generate only for 1 time)
  static Future<void> _generateFcmToken() async {
    try {
      var token = await messaging.getToken();
      if (token != null) {
        print("token : $token");

        // MySharedPref.setFcmToken(token);
        // StorageService.setFcmToken(token);
        _sendFcmTokenToServer();
      } else {
        // retry generating token
        await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5));
        _generateFcmToken();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      // Logger().e(error);
    }
  }

  /// this method will be triggered when the app generate fcm
  /// token successfully
  static _sendFcmTokenToServer() async {
    // var token = StorageService.read('fcm_token');
    // // check is authenticated
    // var isAuthenticated = StorageService.read('isAuthenticated');
    // if (token != null && isAuthenticated != null && isAuthenticated) {
    //   // TODO SEND FCM TOKEN TO SERVER
    //   await AuthNetworkService.to.sendDeviceToken(deviceToken: token);
    // }
  }

  ///handle fcm notification when app is closed/terminated
  /// if you are wondering about this annotation read the following
  /// https://stackoverflow.com/a/67083337
  @pragma('vm:entry-point')
  static Future<void> _fcmBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
    // print("background message : ${message.data}");
    if (message.data.isEmpty && message.data['title'] == null) {
      return;
    }

    // check if platform is android
    if (GetPlatform.isAndroid) {
      AwesomeNotificationsHelper.showNotification(
        id: 1,
        title: message.data['title'] ?? 'Tittle',
        body: message.data['body'] ?? 'Body',
        payload: message.data
            .cast(), // pass payload to the notification card so you can use it (when user click on notification)
        actionButtons: [],
        notificationLayout: NotificationLayout.Default,
      );
    }
    //   if platform is ios
    if (GetPlatform.isIOS) {
      AwesomeNotificationsHelper.showNotification(
        id: 1,
        title: message.notification?.title ?? 'Tittle',
        body: message.notification?.body ?? 'Body',
        payload: message.data
            .cast(), // pass payload to the notification card so you can use it (when user click on notification)
        actionButtons: [],
        notificationLayout: NotificationLayout.Default,
      );
    }
  }

  //handle fcm notification when app is open
  static Future<void> _fcmForegroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
    print("foreground message : ${message.data}");
    if (message.data.isEmpty && message.data['title'] == null) {
      return;
    }

    if (GetPlatform.isAndroid) {
      AwesomeNotificationsHelper.showNotification(
        id: 1,
        title: message.data['title'] ?? 'Tittle',
        body: message.data['body'] ?? 'Body',
        payload: message.data
            .cast(), // pass payload to the notification card so you can use it (when user click on notification)
        actionButtons: [],
        notificationLayout: NotificationLayout.Default,
      );
    }

    // navigate to notification screen
    // Get.toNamed(NotificationScreen.route);
  }

  static Future<void> _onMessageOpenApp(RemoteMessage message) async {
    // print("onMessageOpenApp message : ${message.data}");
    if (message.data.isEmpty && message.data['title'] == null) {
      return;
    }

    if (GetPlatform.isAndroid) {
      AwesomeNotificationsHelper.showNotification(
        id: 1,
        title: message.data['title'] ?? 'Tittle',
        body: message.data['body'] ?? 'Body',
        payload: message.data
            .cast(), // pass payload to the notification card so you can use it (when user click on notification)
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: My suggestion is to use local notification when the app in foreground and you receive a push notification , as i remember reading it some where , that notification in foreground are not show but using local notification will help you acheive what you want

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53219599/flutter-notify-from-top-of-the-screen