# Flutter: Receiving Duplicate Notifications from FCM in Flutter App with Awesome Notifications

Tags: flutter, dart, duplicates, firebase-cloud-messaging, awesome-notifications

I'm developing a Flutter app that uses Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) for push notifications and the Awesome Notifications package for local notifications. However, I've encountered an issue where, upon receiving a single FCM push notification, my app displays two notifications instead of one. This behavior occurs regardless of the app's state (foreground, background, or terminated).

Here's a brief overview of how my app handles FCM notifications:

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:logger/logger.dart';
import '../app/data/local/my_shared_pref.dart';
import 'awesome_notifications_helper.dart';

class FcmHelper {
  // prevent making instance
  FcmHelper._();

  // FCM Messaging
  static late FirebaseMessaging messaging;

  /// this function will initialize firebase and fcm instance
  static Future<void> initFcm() async {
    try {
      // initialize fcm and firebase core
      await Firebase.initializeApp(
          // TODO: uncomment this line if you connected to firebase via cli
          //options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
          );

      // initialize firebase
      messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

      // notification settings handler
      await _setupFcmNotificationSettings();

      // generate token if it not already generated and store it on shared pref
      await _generateFcmToken();

      // background and foreground handlers
      FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen(_fcmForegroundHandler);
      FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_fcmBackgroundHandler);
    } catch (error) {
      // if you are connected to firebase and still get error
      // check the todo up in the function else ignore the error
      // or stop fcm service from main.dart class
      Logger().e(error);
    }
  }

  ///handle fcm notification settings (sound,badge..etc)
  static Future<void> _setupFcmNotificationSettings() async {
    //show notification with sound and badge
    messaging.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
      alert: true,
      sound: true,
      badge: true,
    );

    //NotificationSettings settings
    await messaging.requestPermission(
      alert: true,
      badge: true,
      sound: true,
      provisional: true,
    );
  }

  /// generate and save fcm token if its not already generated (generate only for 1 time)
  static Future<void> _generateFcmToken() async {
    try {
      var token = await messaging.getToken();
      if (token != null) {
        MySharedPref.setFcmToken(token);
        _sendFcmTokenToServer();
      } else {
        // retry generating token
        await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 5));
        _generateFcmToken();
      }
    } catch (error) {
      Logger().e(error);
    }
  }

  /// this method will be triggered when the app generate fcm
  /// token successfully
  static _sendFcmTokenToServer() {
    var token = MySharedPref.getFcmToken();
    // TODO SEND FCM TOKEN TO SERVER
  }

  ///handle fcm notification when app is closed/terminated
  /// if you are wondering about this annotation read the following
  /// https://stackoverflow.com/a/67083337
  @pragma('vm:entry-point')
  static Future<void> _fcmBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
    AwesomeNotificationsHelper.showNotification(
      id: 1,
      title: message.notification?.title ?? 'Tittle',
      body: message.notification?.body ?? 'Body',
      payload: message.data
          .cast(), // pass payload to the notification card so you can use it (when user click on notification)
    );
  }

  //handle fcm notification when app is open
  static Future<void> _fcmForegroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
    AwesomeNotificationsHelper.showNotification(
      id: DateTime.now().microsecond,
      title: message.notification?.title ?? 'Tittle',
      body: message.notification?.body ?? 'Body',
      payload: message.data
          .cast(), // pass payload to the notification card so you can use it (when user click on notification)
    );
  }
}
```

And here's how I initialize AwesomeNotifications:

```
    import 'package:awesome_notifications/awesome_notifications.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

import '../routes/app_pages.dart';

class AwesomeNotificationsHelper {
  // prevent making instance
  AwesomeNotificationsHelper._();

  // Notification lib
  static AwesomeNotifications awesomeNotifications = AwesomeNotifications();

  /// initialize local notifications service, create channels and groups
  /// setup notifications button actions handlers
  static init() async {
    // initialize local notifications
    await _initNotification();

    // request permission to show notifications
    await awesomeNotifications.requestPermissionToSendNotifications();

    // list when user click on notifications
    listenToActionButtons();
  }

  /// when user click on notification or click on button on the notification
  static listenToActionButtons() {
    // Only after at least the action method is set, the notification events are delivered
    awesomeNotifications.setListeners(
        onActionReceivedMethod: NotificationController.onActionReceivedMethod,
        onNotificationCreatedMethod:
            NotificationController.onNotificationCreatedMethod,
        onNotificationDisplayedMethod:
            NotificationController.onNotificationDisplayedMethod,
        onDismissActionReceivedMethod:
            NotificationController.onDismissActionReceivedMethod);
  }

  ///init notifications channels
  static _initNotification() async {
    await awesomeNotifications.initialize(
        null, // null mean it will show app icon on the notification (status bar)
        [
          NotificationChannel(
            channelGroupKey: NotificationChannels.generalChannelGroupKey,
            channelKey: NotificationChannels.generalChannelKey,
            channelName: NotificationChannels.generalChannelName,
            groupKey: NotificationChannels.generalGroupKey,
            channelDescription: NotificationChannels.generalChannelDescription,
            defaultColor: Colors.green,
            ledColor: Colors.white,
            channelShowBadge: true,
            playSound: true,
            importance: NotificationImportance.Max,
          ),
          // NotificationChannel(
          //     channelGroupKey: NotificationChannels.chatChannelGroupKey,
          //     channelKey: NotificationChannels.chatChannelKey,
          //     channelName: NotificationChannels.chatChannelName,
          //     groupKey: NotificationChannels.chatGroupKey,
          //     channelDescription: NotificationChannels.chatChannelDescription,
          //     defaultColor: Colors.green,
          //     ledColor: Colors.white,
          //     channelShowBadge: true,
          //     playSound: true,
          //     importance: NotificationImportance.Max)
        ], channelGroups: [
      NotificationChannelGroup(
        channelGroupKey: NotificationChannels.generalChannelGroupKey,
        channelGroupName: NotificationChannels.generalChannelGroupName,
      ),
      // NotificationChannelGroup(
      //   channelGroupKey: NotificationChannels.chatChannelGroupKey,
      //   channelGroupName: NotificationChannels.chatChannelGroupName,
      // )
    ]);
  }

  //display notification for user with sound
  static showNotification(
      {required String title,
      required String body,
      required int id,
      String? channelKey,
      String? groupKey,
      NotificationLayout? notificationLayout,
      String? summary,
      List<NotificationActionButton>? actionButtons,
      Map<String, String>? payload,
      String? largeIcon}) async {
    awesomeNotifications.isNotificationAllowed().then((isAllowed) {
      if (!isAllowed) {
        awesomeNotifications.requestPermissionToSendNotifications();
      } else {
        // u can show notification
        awesomeNotifications.createNotification(
          content: NotificationContent(
            id: id,
            title: title,
            body: body,
            groupKey: groupKey ?? NotificationChannels.generalGroupKey,
            channelKey: channelKey ?? NotificationChannels.generalChannelKey,
            showWhen:
                true, // Hide/show the time elapsed since notification was displayed
            payload:
                payload, // data of the notification (it will be used when user clicks on notification)
            notificationLayout: notificationLayout ??
                NotificationLayout
                    .Default, // notification shape (message,media player..etc) For ex => NotificationLayout.Messaging
            autoDismissible:
                true, // dismiss notification when user clicks on it
            summary:
                summary, // for ex: New message (it will be shown on status bar before notificaiton shows up)
            largeIcon:
                largeIcon, // image of sender for ex (when someone send you message his image will be shown)
          ),
          actionButtons: actionButtons,
        );
      }
    });
  }
}

class NotificationController {
  /// Use this method to detect when a new notification or a schedule is created
  @pragma("vm:entry-point")
  static Future<void> onNotificationCreatedMethod(
      ReceivedNotification receivedNotification) async {
    // Your code goes here
  }

  /// Use this method to detect every time that a new notification is displayed
  @pragma("vm:entry-point")
  static Future<void> onNotificationDisplayedMethod(
      ReceivedNotification receivedNotification) async {
    // Your code goes here
  }

  /// Use this method to detect if the user dismissed a notification
  @pragma("vm:entry-point")
  static Future<void> onDismissActionReceivedMethod(
      ReceivedAction receivedAction) async {
    // Your code goes here
  }

  /// Use this method to detect when the user taps on a notification or action button
  @pragma("vm:entry-point")
  static Future<void> onActionReceivedMethod(
      ReceivedAction receivedAction) async {
    //  Map<String, String?>? payload = receivedAction.payload;
    // TODO handle clicking on notification
    // example
    // String routeToGetTo = payload['route'];
    //  normal navigation (Get.toNamed) will throw error

    Get.key.currentState?.pushNamed(Routes.dashboard);
  }
}

class NotificationChannels {
  // // chat channel (for messages only)
  // static String get chatChannelKey => "chat_channel";
  // static String get chatChannelName => "Chat channel";
  // static String get chatGroupKey => "chat group key";
  // static String get chatChannelGroupKey => "chat_channel_group";
  // static String get chatChannelGroupName => "Chat notifications channels";
  // static String get chatChannelDescription => "Chat notifications channels";

  // general channel (for all other notifications)
  static String get generalChannelKey => "jobjourney_channel";
  static String get generalGroupKey => "jobjourney group key";
  static String get generalChannelGroupKey => "jobjourney_channel_group";
  static String get generalChannelGroupName =>
      "jobjourney notifications channel";
  static String get generalChannelName => "jobjourney notifications channels";
  static String get generalChannelDescription =>
      "Notification channel for jobjourney notifications";
}
```

How can I identify and resolve the cause of receiving duplicate notifications when using FCM with Awesome Notifications in Flutter? Is there a known issue or conflict between these two notification handling mechanisms that I might be overlooking?

Answer (score 0):

You must send and receive notifications as data.

Ex.

```
message.notification?.title
```

instead

```
message.data["title"] ?? ""
```